# Raspberry Pi remote update of entire OS or NodeJS

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, remote-access

I am new to raspberry pi.
I want to develop small program using Raspberry Pi.
What are the options I have for remote update of Raspberry Pi which I will be giving to my users.

For example I am in New York and my user is in Atlanta and Chicago.
Once i give the raspberry pi with added NodeJS and node program to them.
How can i update it remotely if i want to modify the program or update the OS itself, in case they have any issues considering the fact they have no technical knowledge ?

Is there anyway to control that entire Pi remotely ?

I know the SSH options but that will be on the same network right ?

Some expert help would be great.

Comment: If you have root privileges and you enable a remote terminal connection and the Raspberry Pis are publicly accessible from the internet and you have an IP address for each one, then you can connect to each one of them via a remote terminal and do anything you want to them.

Comment: Hello jfriend00, Can you tell me how can i do this ? I will be having pi with me before i send to them but once i send then what should i do to get access ? How can i get their public ip address to remote into ?

Answer (score 1):

Guess you want to update your node.js app, not the OS.
After all usually apps update themselves, not their host OS.

Anyhow, what I do is I have some public DNS that points to an update server that holds the version and the updated package (tar.gz).
The client PIs just do every once and a while a http request to the update server and check the remote version compared to local version and if remote it bigger, then they do another http request to download the updated package.
Once you downloaded it, just untar and replace the files.
After replacing, I kill the node.js process.
I have an upstart setup to restart the node.js process if its down, so basically after I replaced the files and kill the process the upstart will rerun the node.js but now with updated files.

You could do a simpler solution and have the download server just be some public folder in dropbox or something.
But it really is up to the app you are building and how serious it is :)
PIs are usually for small home projects like what I have (I put a pi in a different location to sync/backup data).

I really suggest not to push via ssh into the remote pis anything as that means they will have to expose themselves to the public internet which from security point of view is definitely not recommended and you will have to set it up in every location (the router rules to expose the pi, setup static IP in local network, setup DNS for client location).
Much simpler and better have those PIs connect to you to PULL the updates.

Comment: Thanks Sagie, This is what i decided now. Checking the updated version number everytime program starts and if new version is available then download and replace the existing one. I am new to unix so do you have any sample which shows starting one process of update then stopping and then starting main process again if everything is updated ? I have my amazon instance which can provide the updated package of the program in .zip or ta.gz. What is the best to choose between these two. how to do upstart ?

Comment: I was sure you would be doing it in your nodejs app, not unix shell. In unix you can do a simple http get via wget (wget <url>) which will download the resource that can be a file with version number, or tar.gz with the actual update. than do untar or unzip (usually tar.gz is used and not zip but it won't make much difference to you). But this is a whole new question that is kinda hard to answer in a comment since I can't even push code snippets here

Comment: Did that and working now. So Program update will be possible now all time.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion. You can use git and webhooks. It's a breeze and a convenient way to maintain version history too. You should also look into continuous integration.